# Server Side Validation - how to start?

Tags: php

I've got a little issue about validating PHP variables from a form.

For example: 
I post a variable from a form to a PHP file.

```
$event_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['event-name']);
if ($event_name=='' || $event_name==null)
{
    /* send error message */
}
```

I used the above code and got an error whenever the $_POST['event-name'] is empty.
Will there be any problem/consequence if I use it like:

```
$event_name = $_POST['event-name'];
if (mysql_real_escape_string($event_name)=='' || mysql_real_escape_string($event_name)==null)
 {
    /* send error message */
 }
```

Or am I doing it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You should escape the string *after* validation. The best way to do escaping is just before inserting into the database - you don't want to work with escaped data in other parts of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) method is used to see if there is something in the POST. Suggest using the following method:

```
if (!isset($_POST['event-name']) || $_POST['event-name'] == "")
{
    /* send error message */
}
else
    $event_name = $_POST['event-name'];
```

only use `mysql_real_escape_string` at the point of issuing the mysql query.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be using this one.

Answer (score 0):

You probably got error "undefined index **event-name**", if [E_STRICT](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) error reporting is enabled.

So it's better to check if variable is not [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
 if (!empty($_POST['event-name'])) { 
     $event_name = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['event-name']); //espace variables after validation.
 }
```

Comment: beware the empty will be true if you have &event-name=0 as a query parameter. the empty function is a false-friend wrt "0". cf http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.empty.php

Comment: Yes you are right, maybe here this kind of checking is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think better way do this:

```
$clean = array();

if(isset($_POST['event-name']) && ctype_alpha($_POST['event-name']) && trim($_POST['event-name']) != "")
{
  $clean['event-name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['event-name']);
}
else
{
  // process error message
}
```